# Integrating Observables into Blazor Fluxor Effects like in Angular

Tags: redux, rxjs, blazor-webassembly, system.reactive, fluxor

I come from an Angular background switching over to Blazor. Since I like the redux pattern and have used NGRX with Angular, I'm using Blazor Fluxor for statement management, which works well.

Now I want to use Observables in my effects when calling my database instead of Tasks.
While I've learned from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9KJdixlUTMI) how to wrap HTTP requests into Observables, I am unsure on how to tie this in with Fluxor (which I've heard, uses Observables under the hood, is that right?).

My main reason for wanting to do this is, that I want to minimise unnecessary database calls. E.g. I'm dispating actions to load data from the database on navigating to different pages. If the loading takes a long time and the user navigates away from and back to the page, a second action is dispatched, querying the database for the same data, in parallel to the first query. In RXJS, I would have used the [exhaustMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/exhaustmap) operator to ignore those requests until the preceeding request completes.

In Angular, I would have done something like this

```js
export const getAnimalsEffect = createEffect((actions$ = inject(Actions)) => {
  const gql = inject(GetAnimalsGQL); // <-- service which makes http requests
  return actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AnimalsPageActions.getAnimals),
    exhaustMap(() => gql.fetch().pipe(
        map(animalsQueryResult => animalsQueryResult.data.animals.map(m => m as IAnimal)),
        map(animals => AnimalsApiActions.getAnimalsSuccess(animals)),
        catchError(e => of(AnimalsApiActions.getAnimalsFailure(e)))
    ))
  )}, { functional: true }
);
```

In Fluxor, this currently looks like this

```cs
public class AnimalsEffects(IState<AnimalsState> state, IGqlClient client)
{
    [EffectMethod] public async Task OnGetAnimals(GetAnimals action, IDispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await client.GetAnimals.ExecuteAsync(); // <-- http request
            dispatcher.Dispatch(new GetAnimalsSuccess(result.Data!));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            dispatcher.Dispatch(new GetAnimalsFailure(ex.Message));
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any starters for me? As far as I know, the effect method must return a task, so just wrapping the request in `Observable.FromAsync()` wont work.

Comment: PS: I came across Fluxor's [ActionSubscriber](https://github.com/mrpmorris/Fluxor/tree/master/Source/Tutorials/01-BasicConcepts/01E-ActionSubscriber) which lets me subscribe to specific actions and thought it would help me. But I guess I am missing the ability to subscribe to the "stream of all actions" and also it does not exposre as an observable...